# Border in right side of UITableViewCell not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add border around table view cell. Following is the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.separatorInset.left = 20.0
        cell.separatorInset.right = 20.0
        cell.separatorInset.top = 20.0
        cell.separatorInset.bottom = 20.0
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 3
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.colorWithHexString("80CBC4").CGColor
        return cell
    }
```

The border is working for three sides, except right side:
[image]

[image]

Comment: have defined the `width` and `height` constraint for the cell view

Comment: Try solution from my recent answer...

Comment: So the border you want is light teal on the top and bottom and white on the left and right with the radius ? Also, there are a few issues with the way you're building the cell. Eg. The width is specified as 574 and I'm pretty sure you can move all the layout code to the IB

Comment: @user1349663 Programmatically, I am adding only the border, the width I have left as the default one. And the the problem was that I had forgotten to specify the constraints for the table view itself, and not the cell view.

Comment: @triple.s Sounds like you've figured it out :) I would still move all the cell layout code to a custom cell class if you can't do it in IB but that might just be personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Try your code with `maskToBounds` set to `true`  layer's property:

> When the value of this property is `true`, Core Animation creates an implicit clipping mask that matches the bounds of the layer and includes any corner radius effects. If a value for the mask property is also specified, the two masks are multiplied to get the final mask value.
>   The default value of this property is `false`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.separatorInset.left = 20.0
        cell.separatorInset.right = 20.0
        cell.separatorInset.top = 20.0
        cell.separatorInset.bottom = 20.0
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 3
        cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.colorWithHexString("80CBC4").CGColor
        cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds  = true
        return cell
}
```

Comment: still having the same result

Comment: So I guess cell width is equal to screen width, right?

Comment: Yes.. I have added another snapshot of my `xib` and app on simulator.

Comment: Well, I guess your border exists, but inside invisible to user area... Try to decrease cell width just to debug my idea...

Comment: The problem was I was missing constraints for the `tableView` and not the `cellView`

Comment: can you explain further please because I've not set nor changed my UITableViewControllers 'table' constraints (it doesn't use them) and I'm having this on small screen devices, but not on large ones.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably specified a fixed width constraint.
You should remove it and specify the leading and trailing constraints.

Comment: The problem was I was missing constraints for the `tableView` and not the `cellView`